# Seems that admin_post_{action} does not executing

Tags: admin, wp-admin, hooks

I'm trying to proccess different actions of my plugin with admin_post_{action} hook.

But following code seems not working

```
class TestPlugin {

   function test(){
      die('working!');
   }

   function __construct(){
     add_action( 'admin_post_test', array($this, 'test'));
   }
}

new TestPlugin();
```

I'm tring to fire this event by following url: https://test.local/wp-admin/edit.php?page=test-plugin%2Ftest-plugin.php&action=test

Answer (score 5):

It's simply the wrong endpoint. The `admin_post_*` hook and its `admin_post_nopriv_*` counterpart is not fired for any admin page with the appropriate `action` request variable set, it **only** triggers for requests hitting `wp-admin/admin-post.php`.

Try https://test.local/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=test instead.

---

I should add that using `admin-post.php` for handling plugin actions might not be appropriate. If you wanted to return the user to their page of origin, then you would need to redirect them and would loose their request data This is terrible UX if, for example, you are returning them because a form field was invalid, as those forms would now be blank.